# Get All Fans of My Facebook Page via API for streaming content

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to get all users (uid) which like my fan page, but I haven't found any method in the Facebook API. Does this function exist?

How I can stream a content in the wall of all of my users fan?

Answer (score 2):

Just because somebody is your fan, that doesn't mean that you can automatically stream anything on their walls. Imagine, if [Lady GaGa](http://www.facebook.com/ladygaga) will decide to do that and write something on 28 million walls. Basically the API gives you the permission to do anything you could do as a simple user. Anything extra, you have to ask for a permission from the users.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Apparently this works, even though it's not documented!: `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID_OR_PAGE_NAME/members?access_token=XXXX`</strike>

This is **NOT** possible! Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page/5186725#5186725)!