# Facebook FQL get the list of fans of a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

Currently all the solutions on this site don't work. I am an admin on a facebook page and would like to export the ID's off all my fans, is this possible ?

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id= [PAGE_ID]&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: no longer possible, see [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

---

FQL:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = <page_id>
```

Comment: says it needs an oauth access token, I am currently logged in as the admin, and given an access token a page_id says its invalid

Comment: see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ the part with: In order to authenticate your app, you must pass the authorization code and your app secret to the Graph API token endpoint at https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. The app secret is available from the Developer App and should not be shared with anyone or embedded in any code that you will distribute

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE` so you get an accesstoken for the fql request.

Comment: where it says: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Comment: try `SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=<page_id>`

Comment: I get <fql_query_response list="true"/>. I am opening this in the browser, is there a special way to see this ? or is the list just empty

Comment: will be empty. there was a way via the old rest api, but it seems FB has closed all ways via FQL to get the data.

Comment: So there is really no way to see my list of fans ?

Comment: @daniel did you find a solution? i am tryin rufinus solution but that didn't work. For posts it does work but not for page_id?? i am getting error 604 "Your statement is not indexable..."

Comment: yes the solution is to not use facebook at all, this is not possible, facebook API sucks too much..

Comment: try SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=<page_id> – Rufinus Jun 14 '11 at 0:20 - that will NOT work, because The object_id is id of a video, note, link, photo, or album.

Comment: `will be empty. there was a way via the old rest api, but it seems FB has closed all ways via FQL to get the data. – Rufinus Jun 14 '11 at 0:24` - you should read all comments pal.