# How do I get a list of users who liked a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get a list of users who liked my page.

Is that possible to getting user detail?

I used following FQL query but its shows me a blank JSON response

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=1234567
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to be possible via the API. You'll have to query with specific user ids to see if they like a certain page. See these two posts for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337739/facebook-fql-get-the-list-of-fans-of-a-facebook-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/10906320/2151050