# Facebook Api get fan list of the page i'm managing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a user's `manage_pages` permission and I can access the user's page info.

Is there a way that I can get the list of users who liked this page  ?

When I go to /me/likes with the page's access_token I only see the pages who liked this page.

How can I see the regular users who liked it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy reasons, it´s not possible to get a list of all the fans of a Page. You would not be allowed to do anything with the list anyway (send them stuff and whatnot). A user should only be known by an App if that specific user authorized the App.

More information can be found in several other threads about this question:

- [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)
- [Facebook FQL get the list of fans of a facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337739/facebook-fql-get-the-list-of-fans-of-a-facebook-page)
- ...

Comment: Its actually doesnt make sense. If i have the admin token that mean the admin gave it to me and hecan see this list anyhow on facebook. I need it for analytical propses not for spamming :)

Comment: the admin can´t see the whole list, only the last few. and since you would not get any user details (only name and picture), the data would be senseless for analytical stuff. that´s what the insights are for anyway.

Comment: lets agree to disagree on that :) although its only their name and pictures and can be used to different analytical usage. But thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: well, using their name and pictures for analytical stuff would not be allowed at all without the permission of the user, that´s all private data ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /v8.0/{page-id}/?fields=fan_count HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#public-page-data