# want to know the list of users who liked my brand page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

I am new to Facebook development and I created one Brand page. I would like to know the list of users who liked my brand page.

I can see the list of people who liked my page on left side of menu under "Like this". Is there any way where we can retrieve those list and store somewhere?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid due to policies there is no real way to extract this information. It' supposed to protect the users, or something.

You can check if a specific Facebook user likes your page, though.

Comment: Check a specific user? You need to take a look at their documents for that: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) You need to get access_token and some other stuff to do an API to Facebook. Too complex to be explained here.