# How to get the users who like your page?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

I'm trying to develop a small app which takes all the users who like my page and randomly returns one. The only thing I can't find is how to get the users who like my page. Is there a way to do it or not?