# Facebook App - to make app or fetch pic

Tags: facebook

I wanted to do something really cool for all my Facebook fanpage fans (10000 in total) but for that I need those 10000 profile pics. But Facebook only allows to see 500 profiles of fans at a time. I tried every method possible, but am not able to see all my 10000 fans in list (if so then I can simple save there pics).

If there is no way to get all those pics, then I intend to make a Facebook app which I can put on my landing page of fan page, which can ask user to click a button, and by clicking that button - the user's profile pic gets fetched. if I get his ID also then it's great, but that's not mandatory, just pic would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a separate application to get your fans' profile pictures.

Facebook Open Graph objects are paged. As such, you can only retrieve 500 fans at a time, but you can make subsequent requests to obtain the rest of them by issuing a request as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/planhero/members?limit=500&offset=0&access_token=[access_token]
https://graph.facebook.com/planhero/members?limit=500&offset=500&access_token=[access_token]
```

The following pages may be useful:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

**Edit:**

It is not possible to query the fans of a Facebook page.

- [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)
- http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12880

Comment: sure, i would give it a try. But I found through firebug that after I make the request above the limit=400 then the FB shows some kind of error or sometimes shows 'Wrong Page' kind of things. I have not used the same URL as you suggested but that was kind of the same. And one more thing, are you sure that I would never end up getting duplicate entries, if I use this method. Thanks for your reply. Appreciate that.

Comment: As long as you set your `offset` properly, you will not receive duplicate entries. The `offset` tells Facebook to return entries from that value onward. So `limit=500&offset=500` would return users 500 - 999.

Comment: and please shed some light on [access_token]. Thanks.

Comment: I get this error in both URLs

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 604
   }
}

Comment: After searching for a few minutes, I've learned this is not possible. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page.

Comment: so can you suggest me anything about that second alternative solution of making an app