# graph api - retrieve list of likes of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been searching & found it's probably not possible.. but I thought I'd ask anyway:

I have this facebook page & I'd like to display the user-images(=avatars) of everyone who liked my page. I think it's really strange this isn't possible using the facebook API!

So basically I need to retrieve a list of users who liked my page. Something like this: (yet likes doesn't exist).

https://graph.facebook.com/page_name/likes?access_token=token

If I'd use the simple facebook plugin - it does display user images of people who liked my page.; so how come the plugin can retrieve these images but API can not ?

Any help is much appreciated!

thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

Comment: What “plugin” are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an API call or FQL query you can call to get the list of users who like the page. Facebook has prevented this type of call for privacy reasons. You should stick with using the plugin instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info - but I don't see how the plugin provides "more" privacy as the call would/could do exactly the same..

Comment: it does provide more privacy, as it only shows a small portion of the users, and if you are logged in the portion will most likely show your friends first. also, if you would get access to the user list with the api, you could easily spam the users automatically.
the answer is correct, there is no way to do this with the api, fortunately. why would you need the list of your fans anyway?

Comment: Thanks - the thing is, even if just a small portion, I want to display pictures of the fans of the page in a design I created.. I rather not use the default plugin as it doesn't really look good! I'd like some more freedom with the user-images that are displayed...

Comment: It would be good, but it's just not doable. Unless you know the user_ids of the fans...