# Facebook api likes

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to know if that's possible using the Facebook API?

1. Get everyone that liked my page (Less than 50 people)
2. Get all the pages they liked
3. Query to see if any of the people that liked my page liked my competitor page as well?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

1. No way. Reference: [graph api - retrieve list of likes of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859762/graph-api-retrieve-list-of-likes-of-a-page)
2. Request **https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/likes** endpoint. Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/
3. Request **https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}** endpoint. Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

3.1 Request FQL to check multiple userid in only one API call, for example, if one of the user id from the list (e.g. 4,5,12345,777) have liked the page, it would return the relevant user id, i.e. 12345 as shown in this screenshot.

SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 279183048899677 AND uid In (4,5,12345,777)

[image]

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Comment: 2) and 3) can only be used if you gathered an User Access Token via an App first.

Answer (score 0):

**[Facebook](http://facebook.com)** dismiss FQL after 8 Augsut 2016 Now you need to use only [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Thanks For your Guidance..I'll try to post more better answer