# FQL NoIndexFunctionException 604 page_fan

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I used FQL query:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = <page_id>
```

it returns me this error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an             indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
"type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
"code": 604
}
}
```

on this site : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan
all columns that i used are indexed.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: "Facebook and Stack Exchange are now working together to support the Facebook developer community. Facebook engineers participate here along with the best Facebook developers in the world. If you have a technical question about Facebook, this is the best place to ask."

and where is the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer get a list of users who like a page using `FQL`. This is done so by design.

If you look at the reference for [`fql/page_fan`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan) you can see that `uid` is the only column that is fully indexed, whereas the other indexed columns are only partially indexed. This means that you need to use `uid` in conjunction with the other partially index columns.

**This will work**

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid = A AND page_id = B
```

**Whereas this will not**

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid = A
```

---

Also see "[Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)", which deals with what you are trying to do.