# How to get Facebook likes on a website to also show on Facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I have a website which has numerous static pages that users can like and this like will then appear within their own timeline.  I also have a Facebook app which when a user likes something on my website I want the like to appear on the app page.  Can anybody tell me if this is possible?

I have configured the og headers and included the meta properties on my web page including the fb:appid but I can't get the likes to appear!

Comment: Hmm looks maybe not.., do you have any code so far>?

Comment: OK, so getting the names of the people is not possible because of FAcebook's own policy - see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page  . But I'd guess you can see that somebody liked it..