# Get users who liked my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get users who liked my page through Facebook Graph Api? Basically, I want to get last 5 users who liked my page.

I can't find it anywhere in the docs and endpoint **/page/likes** return likes which page made, not who likes page.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible. Have a look at this [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/147185208750426).

You can also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page) discussion and can try to find a workaround to this problem. This bug is around 1 year old, so I think you might find a way achieve this. There have been a lot of discussion on this on StackOverflow.