# Facebook Graph API - See user which liked our page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an entrance app for some events at a congress.
Only users which liked our company-facebook page before should be allowed to enter.

I was reading around the last days, that it is not possible (only if the user logged in with facebook connect on our site) to see via the Graph API, which users liked our page? We would have the email adress (over an external registration form), but not the FacebookID.

I'm wondering if there are solutions outside, which i didn't found...

Comment: How do you have the email ids of all the users of your page?

Comment: Over an external registration form..

Comment: But how are you sure that you have the email of all the users who liked your page

Comment: The workflow is following: first he registers, then he should have the possibility to like our page. when he comes to the congress, he grants entrance if he liked it before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not** possible to get the list of users who have liked your page.

But since you are having the email_ids of the users who have liked the page, you were left with one thing - searching users with email_id BUT unfortunately this has been disallowed by facebook. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335452696581712). It says-

> The ability to pass in an e-mail address into the "user" search type was removed on July 10, 2013. This search type only returns results that match a user's name (including alternate name).

For future ref, if you have some application, you can query for `/me` and save their facebook ids.