# Facebook Graph API – Top Fan Badges

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Facebook has quite recently introduced a feature called Top Fan Badges (more info [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/215734232362020) and [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/340991076472172)). I would like to make use of this feature via the Graph API, so that I can

- (preferably): query weather or not a given user id is a 'top fan' for my page
- list all top fans of my page

I did not find anything on the docs, neither on the [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) nor the [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) node. The information which user is a top fan is publicly visible on the page (/pagename/community) and could – in theory, probably breaking Facebook TOS – be scraped. But that's not desirable, obviously.

I am aware that listing users who like a page does [not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page) via Graph API. Yet, I was hoping that I could query at least the status of a single given user.

Any insights or ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently not reflected via the API and I doubt that it'll be introduced in upcoming API versions.

Comment: Is this api available now ?